# Window switcher for multiple windows of the same app does not appear with mouse hover

Tags: gnome, window, application-switcher

After enabling 'resize with secondary click' using GNOME Tweaks, window switcher for multiple windows of the same app does not appear with mouse hover over icon. Any way to get it back? I can get to the list of windows by right clicking on the icon and hovering over "all windows", but I would rather do it by just hovering over the icon.